# bundle failed: 'CloudModule' is not exported

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm trying to add push notification to my Ionic2 app. I'm following [this](https://docs.ionic.io/setup.html#installation). My app was working correctly before doing `ionic io init` as suggested in the ionic2 push doc page now I keep getting this error everytime I do `ionic serve`

```
bundle failed: 'CloudModule' is not exported by node_modules/@ionic/cloud-angular/dist/es5/index.js 
            (imported by src/app/app.module.ts). For help fixing this error see https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work I had to add this to my file rollup.config.js as suggested in [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cloud-angular/issues/21)

node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/rollup.config.js

```
module.exports = {

  [...]
  useStrict: false,
   [...]

  plugins: [
    ngTemplate(),
    commonjs({
        include: [
         [...]
        'node_modules/@ionic/cloud-angular/**',
        'node_modules/superagent/**',
        'node_modules/@ionic/cloud/node_modules/superagent/**',
        'node_modeule/emitter/**',
        'node_modules/reduce-component/**',
        'node_modules/intl/**',
        'node_modules/**',
        ],
        namedExports: {
          [...]
        }
    }),
    nodeResolve({
      useStrict: false,
      module: true,
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
      browser: true,
      extensions: ['.js']
    })
  ]

};
```

even if this makes build process slow